# Time taken to travel between two points in map - iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-sdk-3.0

How to calculate the time taken to travel between two points in the map view.

Comment: Which information do you have? Two locations (time, coordinates) recorded by GPS? or simply to coordinates (latitude, longitude)

Comment: Coordinates(latitude,longitude) of two points.

Comment: That is not sufficient, time to travel with vehicle? or by feet?or by airplane????

Comment: Does iphone store timestamps along with location co-ordinates?

Comment: You need to provide some of the attributes of the problem when asking... off the top of my head how is travel to be done, what is the path length, speed, what retarding factors are there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Measured Travel Time**

You can only do that if you have the timestamp stored together with the coordinates of the points. Other solutions are unrealistic. If you have both timestamps, then it is simple to calculate the difference in number of seconds.

Convert both times to "timeSinceReferenceDate" and subtrac:

something like deltaSeconds = abs(t2 - t1);

**Estimated Traveltime automotive**

If you have only coordinates, and want to know the **estimated** travel time by using a car, you have to use a routing service, which calculates the route and time duration for your you.